# How to insert variable value in mysql insert query?

Tags: mysql

I have written aa insert query in a stored procedure...

```
   INSERT INTO `ascencom_soa2`.`rardata` (`threatDescription`,`rtpControlObjective`,
  `rtpNonTechnical`,`rtpISOControl`,
  `rtpWorkInstructions`,`VulnerabilityDescription`,
  `assetname`,`companyid`,`assetid`)

  VALUES (threatDesc,rtpcontrol,
  rtpNon,rtpISO,
  rtpWork,rtpvulnarabilityDesc,
  idAsset,idCompany,idAssetType);
```

Here `threatDesc, rtpcontrol, trpNon....` are variables and are initialized before the insert query is executed...

but it is give me error...

> 1054 : Unknown column 'threatDesc' in 'field list'

please help me with this problem

Comment: Are you trying to do this from within a MySQL client, or via PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@threatDesc, @rtpcontrol, @trpNon...
```

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no column threatDesc so you can't assign it as a value. My guess is that you either meant to put quotes around that and save it as a string, OR you are trying to assign from another table and you need to say tableName.threatDesc OR something else entirely.